# How to treat index.cgi as a directory index in Eclipse EPIC Perl CGI?

Tags: eclipse, perl, cgi

I am using the Eclipse EPIC (Perl Editor and IDE for Eclipse) Plugin's "Perl CGI" debug and run configuration on a site that uses index.cgi as it's directory index file. The site was written expecting the Apache DirectoryIndex to be index.html index.cgi, so most links just point to the directory and not to index.cgi. This results in getting 404 responses if index.html does not exist instead of displaying the results of index.cgi.

Is there a setting to make EPIC Perl CGI emulate the behavior of Apache's `DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi` so that it serves index.cgi instead of 404 when it is available?

Answer (score 0):

So far I have found no setting to configure this. The content seems to be served by a java process started by Eclipse. For now I'm scattering index.html files around with meta refresh tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='index.cgi'" />
```